# SP2013 : Overriding Thumbnails column in PublishingImages library

Tags: 2013, url, calculated-column-formula, image-rendition, thumbnail

I'm really stuck with this one, so if someone has a little time to help me on this...

**What i want :**

I have a pictures library in a site. It is even a PublishingImages library. a lot of my images are .PNG files. So, i want to display a thumbnail of these files along with the name and every property i could get.

**What i have :**

Because these are PNG files with transparent background (and a lot of time, they are white icons), Sharepoint does not generate a good thumbnail and this last turn out to be all white. So, it is not helping.

**What i thought :**

I understood that SP is not good with calculating PNG thumbnails and that my PNG files are converted to JPG etc.. but i would like it to render fine, ok?

So, i thought i would create a new Content Type Column, which should be a html calculated column, with a formula which takes the original path of the file and add it a rendition.

So, instead of having only "Name" and "Thumbnails", i would have "Name", "Thumbnail", "Custom Thumbnail" as columns.
And in Custom Thumbnials, i should have a formula which says `concat(ImageURL,'?RenditionID=9')` for example.

**Do you know how i could manage to calculate my custom column on one other ?**
Do you know how i could manage to do that ?

Thanks a lot for your time and help !!

Comment: You may use FileRef, FileLeafRef columns to get the ImageURL and than append the rendition.. Did you try creating a Calculated Column?

Comment: Hi Arsalan, I tried to create a Calculated column, but the only columns i could add to the Formula are Author, Copyright, Created, height, title and so on.. no url nor file's path in it... Do you have any idea on that ?
thanks to remind me of FileLeafRef, i'll see if i can use it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a new Hyperlink or Picture column to the library and set its value using sharepoint desginer workflow every time a new picture is added. For existing pictures you can use powershell script to set the value of this field.
SharePoint creates 2 thumbnail urls for each uploaded image

1.http://sitename/PublishingImages/_t/2014%20Annual%20Review%20cover_JPG.jpg
2.http://sitename/PublishingImages/_w/2014%20Annual%20Review%20cover_JPG.jpg

Comment: Thanks Harry, i am currently trying to set a workflow.
So, do you have an idea on which column do i have to use to retrieve the url of my image? And, i am working on SP Online, so i can't execute a Powershell script for that.

Comment: you will need to create a workflow variable to type string and constuct the url. for example. http://sitename/PublishingImages/_w/+[imagefilename]+_JPG.jpg?RenditionID=9. You can also use JSLink to create a custom view. JSLink will give you access to much more infomation about the image file.

Comment: You can construct the URL using the image file name in a SP designer WF variable. For SP Online you can use CSOM (Javascript/C#) to update  properties for existing images.